# Web.config save problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to expose some of the web.config settings to a user via the front end of the web app. I can retrieve the settings without a problem, but when I save I either get an error or the changes are not persisted to the web.config file. I am debugging in VS.

If I run this:

```
    private void SaveWebConfig()
    {
        Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~//Web.config");
        webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["DocumentPath"].Value = this.txtDocumentsDirectory.Text;
        webConfig.Save();
    }
```

I get the following error:
A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object.

If I run this code, nothing happens:

```
 private void SaveWebConfig()
 {
     Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~//Web.config");
     webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["DocumentPath"].Value = this.txtDocumentsDirectory.Text;
     webConfig.SaveAs("~//Web.config");
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, and it is rather easy. Whether it works depends on the privileges of the user account that your App runs under.

You are using double forward slashes, and the SaveAs is wrong too. Try:

```
 private void SaveWebConfig()
 {
     Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
     webConfig.AppSettings.Settings["DocumentPath"].Value =
          this.txtDocumentsDirectory.Text;
     webConfig.Save();
 }
```

But you probably should avoid changing the (root) web.config as much as possible. I've only seen this in special pages for the SiteManager to make config changes.

Comment: OK thanks, it would be so that the admin doesn't have to go into web.config himself and configure the settings.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge the web.config should not be altered by the consuming web application. ASP.NET and IIS are built to restart the whole application every time the web.config is updated.

Instead of exposing it expose settings from the database and persist these settings in the db, your front end should not change much only the way you load and save data does.

Comment: amen! can you say "security hole?" I knew you could... :)

Comment: OK, I dont really understand why they would make AppSettings and then have it be a readonly collection of keys that is not update-able from the application, but if thats the case then so be it.

Comment: App settings is general wrapper for the appsetting section, in a windows application you also have app.config and I believe you can actually write to it from application execution, then in IIS / ASP.NET simply you can't but they have a generic API... we can discuss hours if it could have been a nice idea or not to throw an exception in the ASP.NET implementation, but in fact the .NET Framework is generic and the class is inside System.Configuration assembly...

Comment: To be clear, you _can_ alter web.config from a Web App. Whether that's a good idea is another matter.