# Difference between web.config and normal xml file for storing application settings

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config

I have an application which have some specific settings like erroremailid, maxcapcount etc. 
I am storing these values in appsetting block. Can anybody tell me which will be better (performance wise) between following two options:
1. Storing settings in web.config
2. Storing settings in normal xml file and then reading them

Some articles specifying the performance difference will also be good.

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is not about performances, why do you think the .NET framework would be any faster in reading one xml file vs another one?

The way .NET works is that certain settings (not only the appSettings section) are retrieved from the application configuration file which is `web.config` for ASP.NET and `exefile.exe.config` for executable applications.

in executables like windows forms applications you can also save settings from the app at runtime in the config file but in ASP.NET even if the APIs being the same will let you call the save method, the web.config will not be updated as it's opened as readonly because every time it is changed IIS restarts the web application.

there is no way to imagine that putting some other custom settings in another separated XML file would be any slower or any faster, the advantage vs the web.config would be that you can edit such xml file anytime without the web app to restart as it would happen anytime you save changes in web.config.

still. .NET will get the appSettings from web.config so you can put in another file only other kind of settings and then you have to read those settings yourself by hand, not sure if you can instruct the ConfigurationManager to read from another file.

There are many other sections inside the web.config that are taken by other parts of the application and if you would move them somewhere .NET would not automatically take those for you, for example the default SMTP Server.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is the inheritance wep.config files give you - each file inherits from previous folders up the AppDomain hierarchy.

Comment: I got a comment a friend that web.config is COM wrapper, so it will be slower then reading an xml file? I said that both will be same in term of performance, but I did not have any reference for my explaination.

Answer (score 2):

you have several classes already at your disposal that allow you to read settings from your web.config. if you choose to use your own xml file you will have to write the code to read the values yourself (not that it is particularly difficult, though)

performance wise, the web.config values are read once and strored in memory (again, you could do this yourself if you implement your own class to read settings from your xml) therefore it's fast.

the other difference is that asp.net detects changes to the web.config file automatically and loads them again when this happens. so potentially you can point your app, for example, to a different database <s>at runtime w/o recycling the application.</s> and the application will pick up the changes immediately w/o you recycling the app manually.

Comment: @ Icarus I thought xmls could be updated on the fly? not web.configs?

Comment: web.config also. there are methods for this. google it a bit. I'm walking now and I'm on a cell.

Comment: no problem, I wanted to double check I need to edit my answer now. Thanks!

Comment: no, you are not going to save changes in the web.config from the running asp net application, you can call the APIs but nothing will be saved or IIS will restart the app. Glad to be proven wrong if you have the link ;-)

Comment: @DavidePiras I refer to this kind of thing: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=102 but yes, the moment you touch the Web.config the app will be restarted. I will clarify that in my answer, I should have said `**manually** recycling the app`

Comment: @DavidePiras Were you glad that I proved you wrong or not? ;)

Comment: yep, thanks I learnt something new, see here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578857/web-config-save-problem

Answer (score 0):

webconfig for settings that are not going to change (Can use built in methods to make them update on the fly though).

If you have a lot of settings that are being changed, then storing as a seperate XML would be a better solution, since you can update them on the fly.

**EDIT:**

After finding some new information it is possible to use webconfig settings on the fly as well using built in methods. (See Icarus's answer)